# Data scraping from dynamic sites

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping data from dynamic site (https://www.mozzartbet.com/sr#/betting) using this code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = s)

driver.get('https://www.mozzartbet.com/sr#/betting')
driver.maximize_window()

results = driver.find_elements('xpath', '//*[@id="focus"]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/article/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/span[2]/span')
for result in results:
    print(result.text)
```

I want to scrape quotes from all matches in Premier League and once this code worked properly, and for some reason when I ran it next time it didn't make list results (it contained 0 elements), although I tried that xpath in inspect section of web page and it returned what I wanted, path is in code above.

Comment: You sure the url works?

Comment: url is correct but i found when i delete spans it returns all quotes of matches, not onlyones that i wanted to scrape